# Projective module base change

Tags: vector-bundles, projective-module, k-theory

Let $M$ be a finitely generated projective $C[0,1]$-module. Without using any vector bundle theory, how does one show that the pullback of $M$ along the evaluation at
$0$ and evaluation at $1$ maps are isomorphic? What happens we next try and formulate the same problem for $A[0,1]$, where $A$ is arbitrary unital C*-algebra?